# ADF change label direction

Tags: oracle-adf

**ADF input text**

> the label 1 word will appear on the left hand side can i change it to appear on

the right hand side.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 outputTexts or panelLabelMessage (one left, the other on the right) and render (visible or rendered) to correct one using some EL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a inputText without label and OutputText with your label name and surround these two components with PanelLabelAndMessage.

> ```
>         <af:panelLabelAndMessage label="" id="p1">
>           <af:inputText label="" id="it1"/>
>           <af:outputText value="Your Label Name" id="ot1"/>
>         </af:panelLabelAndMessage>
> ```

Comment: panelLabelAndMessage make it appears one above the other

Comment: You can use PanelGroupLayout inside panelLabelAndMessage and set  property layout="horizontal"

Answer (score 0):

```
<af:panelFormLayout id="pfl1">
  <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl3" layout="horizontal">
        <af:inputText label="" id="it1"/>
        <af:outputText value="label1" id="ot1"/>
  </af:panelGroupLayout>
```

Comment: Try this. I think it would help you